# How to open incognito window from current instance?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, session-cookies, incognito-mode

I have a situation where I need to open a link incognito window from another url.
I have tried by using action class to perform control shift n key events but it's not working.

Robot class working fine but I'm looking for other alternative.

```java
Actions act = new Actions(driver);

act. KeyDown(Keys.cONTROL);

act.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT);

act.keyDown("n").build().  perform ();
```

But it's not working

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to open a new window in incognito mode i.e. without cookies you can simply open a regular new Selenium driver new window and the to clear the cookies with the following command:

```java
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```